# Counting grep result wont work in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

My question is not easy to ask, I try explain the problem with the following example:

/home/luther/tipical_surnames.txt

```
Smith
Johnson
Williams
Jones
Brown
#Davis
Miller
Wilson
#Moore
Taylor
Anderson
```

/home/luther/employers.txt

```
2000    Johnson     A lot-of details / BJC3000,6000, i550                0
2101    Smith       A lot-of details / BJC3000,6000, i550                0
2102    Smith       A lot-of details / BJC3000,6000, i550                0
2103    Jones       A lot-of details / BJC3000,6000, i550                0
2104    Johnson     A lot-of details / BJC3000,6000, i550                0
2100    Smith       A lot-of details / BJC3000,6000, i550                0
```

I have a list with the favorite surnames and another with the name of employers.
Let's check how many people have the most popular surname in the company, using console:

```
grep -v "#" /home/luther/tipical_surnames.txt | sed -n 1'p' | cut -f 1
Smith
grep Smith /home/luther/employers.txt | wc -l
230
```

Work perfect.
Now lets check the first 5 most popular surnames using a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
while [ $counter -le 5 ]
 do
  surname=`grep -v "#" /home/luther/tipical_surnames.txt | sed -n "$counter"'p' | cut -f 1`
  qty=`grep "$surname" /home/luther/employers.txt | wc -l`
  echo $surname
  echo $qty
  counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
 done
```

And the result the follows:

```
Smith
0
Johnson
0
Williams
0
Jones
0
Brown
0
```

Whats wrong?

**Update:**
Like I wrote I tested the script on other computer and everything is works fine.
After I try the follow:

```
root@problematic:/var/www# cat testfile.bash
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ ))
{
echo $c
}

root@problematic:/var/www# bash testfile.bash
testfile.bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'estfile.bash: line 2: `for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ ))
root@problematic:/var/www# echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.37(1)-release
root@problematic:/var/www#
```

Of course on other computer this simply script work as expected, without error.

Comment: A shell is an an environment from which to call tools, not a tool to manipulate text. The standard, general purpose UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. You're struggling because you're using the wrong tool and it'd be immensely complicated and inefficient to do what you want robustly in shell (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). Throw it away and start over with awk. Post concise, testable sample input and expected output and we can help you.

Comment: I'm guess is you have a file with DOS line terminators. You don't see them when copy/pasting program output, but they will be present in the captured variable, and prevent the final `grep` from matching anything. Try `dos2unix` on the files. For further troubleshooting, the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](//stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has a detailed section about this problem.

Comment: @Ed Morton Ok, its clear, but I still dont understand why my code gonna be good if I replace the $surname variable to a value. As you see from the result the $surname variable have a good value when I want print it to the screen. Why the same variable wont work when I use when declare the $qty variable?

Comment: @tripleee Thank you I tried it, but the problem may be something other.

Comment: Also explore `grep -c` for counting occurrences.

Comment: Something like `sort <(cut -f2 /home/luther/employers.txt) | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5` is also interesting.

Comment: Try `set -x` just before `qty=...` and `set -` after that line. You should see what is grepped in the loop.

Comment: Are both the real filename and the filename in the code written as tipical and not typical?

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously untested since you haven't posted sample input but this is the kind of approach you should use:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { if (!/#/) cnt[$1]=0; next }
{ cnt[$WHATEVER]++ }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (name in cnt) {
        print name, cnt
        if (++c == 5) {
            break
        }
    }
}
' /home/luther/tipical_surnames.txt /home/luther/employers.txt
```

Replace "WHATEVER" with the field number where employee surnames are stored in employers.txt.

The above uses GNU awk for sorted_in, with other awks I'd just remove the PROCINFO line and the count from the output loop and pipe the output to sort then head, e.g.:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { if (!/#/) cnt[$1]=0; next }
{ cnt[$WHATEVER]++ }
END {
    for (name in cnt) {
        print name, cnt
    }
}
' /home/luther/tipical_surnames.txt /home/luther/employers.txt | sort -k2,1nr | head -5
```

or whatever the right sort options are.

Comment: Thanks your solution also, its looks very usefull! But I still dont know why my code wont work.

Comment: Again, shell scripts for processing text are fragile and hard to write robustly/correctly. There's so many things that could be causing the problem it's hard to guess which one is actually doing it.I see you use `cut -f 1` at the end of your `surname=...` line - that will do absolutely nothing with the file format you posted - what did you think it would do? The file you posted only has 1 field so why are you apparently trying to select 1 field when that's all there is in the file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not quite sure.  I tested your script, by copying it and pasting it, with imagined data (`/usr/share/dict/words`) and it seems to work as expected.  I wonder if there is a difference between the script you posted and the script you're running?

While at it, I took the liberty of making it run a bit smoother.  Notice how, in the loop, you read the entirety of the surnames file in each iteration? Also, `grep` + `wc -l` may be replaced by `grep -c`. I'm also adding `-F` to the first invocation of `grep` since the pattern (`#`) is fixed strings. The `grep` into the employee file uses `\<$name\>` to make sure we only get the Johns and no Johnssons when `$name` is `John`.

```
#!/bin/bash

employees_in="/usr/share/dict/words"
names_in="/usr/share/dict/words"

grep -v -F "#" "$names_in" | head -n 5 | cut -f 1 |
while read -r name; do
    count="$( grep -c "\<$names\> " "$employees_in" )"
    printf "name: %-10s\tcount: %d\n" "$name" "$count"
done
```

Testing it:

```
$ bash script.sh
name: A             count: 1
name: a             count: 1
name: aa            count: 1
name: aal           count: 1
name: aalii         count: 1
```

Note: I get only ones in the count because the dictionary (not surprisingly) contains only unique words.

Comment: Thanks your reply and your solution. No difference between the pasted codes. I tried it with an other computer and with a generated source files and its really working normal. The problem may be with the source files.

Comment: @Luther Yes, if the employee file is empty or simply doesn't contain the names read from the surnames file (this would be easy to check).  I was under the impression that you ran your first command-line example and the script on the same computer though.

Comment: That will fail when it matches John to Johnston, Smith to Smithers, etc. and when it matches an employee named Johnston with the company name Johnston & Johnston, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks! I'm using `\<..\>`, is that portable?

Comment: No it's GNU-specific and while it'll solve the surname partial match problem it won't solve the employee vs employer name (or surname vs forename or ...) false matches problem.

Comment: @EdMorton Hmmm... GNU `grep` *and* BSD `grep` (on OS X at least).  The format of the employees file is not know, this is the best we can do.

Comment: I suspect the OP knows the format of the employees file, he's just not sharing ;-).

Comment: I just noticed your script is reporting the count of the first 5 names that appear in the names file, not the 5 names that occur most frequently in the employers file (which I assume is what the OP meant by `the first 5 most popular surnames`).

Comment: @EdMorton I merely followed his example. I assumed that the surnames file was either sorted on frequency or that it was just a file of "popular surnames". There's so many mysteries...

Comment: The pasted code is only an example about the problem.

Comment: The real code is much bigger and more complicate. The similiraty of words (like Smith and Smithers)never a problem in the original code and the files never be empty. I made samples from source files: http://pastebin.com/ySzUgjci